# Getting redirected to http://commitse.ru/ when looking for JSON-LD homepage

Tags: json, malware

Whenever I try to go to homepage of JSON-LD (http://json-ld.org), I am being redirected to an apparently malware site (http://commitse.ru/). I have no clue as to why this is happening or any workaround to access the JSON-LD homepage.
Can anybody throw some light on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a problem on your side. Nothing wrong with the access to http://json-ld.org from my machine (Germany).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running over 100 sites, & have recently had all of my sites infected with this redirect to http://commitse.ru/. I can tell you a couple things.

First, I've found that whoever is doing this is coming through China Unicom Beijing province network ip `61.135.249.115`. They are using a back door that can be closed in your cpanel. By default the door is left open for anyone to upload files to your web-server.

"Allow anonymous Uploads" checkbox, needs to be unchecked, under FILES/ANONYMOUS FTP. They are replacing the `htaccess` file with their own infected `htaccess`.